# Box2d objects with no friction somehow gaining velocity when colliding

Tags: box2d

What my simulation looks like: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsdGi.png)

all the circles just bounce around within the rectangle. The restitution for all objects is set to 1.f and friction is set 0.f.

Somehow though, because of the large amount of collisions that take place objects seem to be speeding up over time.

Is this due to floating point inaccuracies? How could I go about fixing this?

Comment: Add the image directly, links only are discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a greater than zero damping factor and/or drop the restitution from 1.f. Tweak these two settings till you get the desired effect. And yes, numerical inaccuracies will play into the effects seen.

The [online Box2D 2.3.0 manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf) also offers the following insight:

> When a shape develops multiple contacts, restitution is simulated approximately. This is because Box2D uses an iterative solver. Box2D also uses inelastic collisions when the collision velocity is small. This is done to prevent jitter. See b2_velocityThreshold in b2Settings.h.